# Postfix combinations of TLS/STARTTLS and ports 465/587

Tags: ssl, postfix, email-server

I'm setting up a barebones Postfix mail server and have this observation:

- TLS works on port 465
- STARTTLS works on port 587
- TLS does NOT work on port 587
- STARTTLS does NOT work on port 465

Is this normal SMTP behavior or is it specific to Postfix? I was reading that using port 465 was discouraged and not RFC compliant.

https://www.mailgun.com/blog/which-smtp-port-understanding-ports-25-465-587

Is it then not possible to be RFC compliant on port 587, AND use TLS instead of STARTTLS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this normal SMTP behavior or is it specific to Postfix?

This is normal behavior.
Port 25 (smtp) and port 587 (submission) are reserved for SMTP with explicit TLS, i.e. plain connect and upgrade to TLS with the STARTTLS command. Port 465 (smtps) is reserved for SMTP with implicit TLS, i.e. TLS right after the TCP connect without any special SMTP command.

Port 25 is always used for MTA to MTA communication, i.e. for the delivery of a mail from one mail server to the next. This is because the server is found using a DNS MX  lookup and there is no support for specifying a port using MX records.

Port 465 and 587 are used by mail clients to submit a mail to the mail server for delivery (in some setups they might also use port 25). These ports usually require also authentication of the client.

> I was reading that using port 465 was discouraged and not RFC compliant.

Explicit TLS is defined in [RFC 3207](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3207.txt). Implicit TLS was defined in  [RFC 8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314#section-3.3) in 2018, which was only after the article you refer to was published.

Comment: Thanks for the details and pointing out the RFCs. I'll look at those to see more of what they say.

Comment: Although the usage of port `465` for SMTPS was revoked in 1998, it has been used for implicit TLS SMTP for these two decades before its offial comeback in RFC 8314. It has been very common to have both configured all this time. The RFC doesn't truly add anything new to this; it just proposes the current situation as a standard.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've used both 587 and 465 when setting up accounts in Gmail, but didn't fully appreciate the difference, nor the ties to TLS or STARTTLS.